# Display list user with gridview android studio

Tags: java, android, listview, gridview

I'm having trouble removing the "parent channel shortcut" even though I already have it hidden **(view2.setvisiblity(view.GONE))**. I'm using gridview **android:numColumns="3"**.The list user display starts from the left side, If I want to remove it, how do I do that?

[image]

```
@Override
        public int getCount() {
            int count = currentusers.size() + subchannels.size() + stickychannels.size();
            if ((curchannel != null) && (curchannel.nParentID > 0)) {
                count++; // include parent channel shortcut
            }
            return count;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {

            if (position < stickychannels.size()) {
                return stickychannels.get(position);
            }

            // sticky channels are first so subtract these
            position -= stickychannels.size();

            if (position < currentusers.size()) {
                return currentusers.get(position);
            }

            // users are first so subtract these
            position -= currentusers.size();

            if ((curchannel != null) && (curchannel.nParentID > 0)) {
                if(position == 0) {
                    Channel parent = ttservice.getChannels().get(curchannel.nParentID);

                    if(parent != null)
                        return parent;
                    return new Channel();
                }

                position--; // subtract parent channel shortcut
            }
            return subchannels.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            if (position < stickychannels.size())
                return INFO_VIEW_TYPE;

            // sticky channels are first so subtract these
            position -= stickychannels.size();

            if (position < currentusers.size())
                return USER_VIEW_TYPE;

            // users are first so subtract these
            position -= currentusers.size();

            if ((curchannel != null) && (curchannel.nParentID > 0)) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    return PARENT_CHANNEL_VIEW_TYPE;
                }

                position--; // subtract parent channel shortcut
            }

            return CHANNEL_VIEW_TYPE;
        }

        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return VIEW_TYPE_COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Object item = getItem(position);

            if(item instanceof Channel) {

                final Channel channel = (Channel) item;

                switch (getItemViewType(position)) {
                    case PARENT_CHANNEL_VIEW_TYPE :
                        // show parent channel shortcut
                        if (convertView == null ||
                                convertView.findViewById(R.id.parentname) == null)
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_channel_back, parent, false);
                            convertView.setVisibility(view.GONE)
                        break;

                    case CHANNEL_VIEW_TYPE :
                        if (convertView == null ||
                                convertView.findViewById(R.id.channelname) == null)
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_channel, parent, false);

                        ImageView chanicon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.channelicon);
                        TextView name = convertView.findViewById(R.id.channelname);
                        TextView topic = convertView.findViewById(R.id.chantopic);
                        Button join = convertView.findViewById(R.id.join_btn);
                        int icon_resource = R.drawable.channel_orange;
                        if(channel.bPassword) {
                            icon_resource = R.drawable.channel_pink;
                            chanicon.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.text_passwdprot));
                            chanicon.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_YES);
                        }
                        else {
                            chanicon.setContentDescription(null);
                            chanicon.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
                        }
                        chanicon.setImageResource(icon_resource);

                        if(channel.nParentID == 0) {
                            // show server name as channel name for root channel
                            ServerProperties srvprop = new ServerProperties();
                            ttclient.getServerProperties(srvprop);
                            name.setText(srvprop.szServerName);
                        }
                        else {
                            name.setText(channel.szName);
                        }
                        topic.setText(channel.szTopic);

                        OnClickListener listener = v -> {
                            if (v.getId() == R.id.join_btn) {
                                joinChannel(channel);
                            }
                        };
                        join.setOnClickListener(listener);
                        join.setAccessibilityDelegate(accessibilityAssistant);
                        join.setEnabled(channel.nChannelID != ttclient.getMyChannelID());

                        if (channel.nMaxUsers > 0) {
                            int population = Utils.getUsers(channel.nChannelID, ttservice.getUsers()).size();
                            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.population)).setText((population > 0) ? String.format("(%d)", population) : "");
                        }

                        break;

                    case INFO_VIEW_TYPE :
                        if (convertView == null ||
                                convertView.findViewById(R.id.titletext) == null)
                            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_info, parent, false);
                        TextView title = convertView.findViewById(R.id.titletext);
                        TextView details = convertView.findViewById(R.id.infodetails);
                        title.setText(channel.szName);
                        details.setText(channel.szTopic);
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if(item instanceof User) {
                if (convertView == null ||
                    convertView.findViewById(R.id.nickname) == null)
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_user, parent, false);
                ImageView usericon = convertView.findViewById(R.id.usericon);
                TextView nickname = convertView.findViewById(R.id.nickname);
                TextView status = convertView.findViewById(R.id.status);
                final User user = (User) item;
                String name = Utils.getDisplayName(getBaseContext(), user);
                nickname.setText(name);
                status.setText(user.szStatusMsg);
                
                boolean talking = (user.uUserState & UserState.USERSTATE_VOICE) != 0;
                boolean female = (user.nStatusMode & TeamTalkConstants.STATUSMODE_FEMALE) != 0;
                boolean away =  (user.nStatusMode & TeamTalkConstants.STATUSMODE_AWAY) != 0;
                int icon_resource;
                
                if(user.nUserID == ttservice.getTTInstance().getMyUserID()) {
                    talking = ttservice.isVoiceTransmitting();
                }
                if(talking) {
                    if(female) {
                        icon_resource = R.drawable.woman_green;
                        nickname.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.user_state_now_speaking, name) + " ");
                    }
                    else {
                        icon_resource = R.drawable.man_green;
                        nickname.setContentDescription(getString(R.string.user_state_now_speaking, name) + " ");
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(female) {
                        icon_resource = away? R.drawable.woman_orange : R.drawable.woman_blue;
                        nickname.setContentDescription(name + " ");
                    }
                    else {
                        icon_resource = away? R.drawable.man_orange : R.drawable.man_blue;
                        nickname.setContentDescription(name + " ");
                    }
                }
                status.setContentDescription(away ? getString(R.string.user_state_away) : null);

                usericon.setImageResource(icon_resource);
                usericon.setImportantForAccessibility(View.IMPORTANT_FOR_ACCESSIBILITY_NO);
                
                Button sndmsg = convertView.findViewById(R.id.msg_btn);
                OnClickListener listener = v -> {
                    if (v.getId() == R.id.msg_btn) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TextMessageActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent.putExtra(TextMessageActivity.EXTRA_USERID, user.nUserID));
                    }
                };
                sndmsg.setOnClickListener(listener);
                sndmsg.setAccessibilityDelegate(accessibilityAssistant);
            }
            convertView.setAccessibilityDelegate(accessibilityAssistant);
            return convertView;
        }
```

The list user display starts from the left side